# Converting VBA Format$ to VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am working on a simple VBA to show tomorrow's meetings from my Outlook calendar. The idea is to schedule this VBA every evening to show the next day's appointments in case I have missed checking them before leaving the office.

To test the code, I wrote it as an MS Excel macro. Here's the full code:

```
Sub getMyAppointmentsForTomorrow()
    Dim objOutlook
    Dim objNameSpace
    Dim objFolder
    Dim MyItems
    Dim CurrentAppointment
    Dim meetingDetails
    Dim dateTomorrowWihoutTime

    Dim restrictionString

    Const olFolderCalender = 9

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalender)
    Set olItems = objFolder.items
    olItems.Sort "[Start]"
    olItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

    myStart = Date
    myEnd = DateAdd("d", 3, myStart)

    StartDate = Format$(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")
    EndDate = Format$(DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate), "mmm-dd-yyyy")

    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _
    Format$(myStart, "mmm-dd-yyyy") _
    & "' AND [End] <= '" & _
    Format$(myEnd, "mmm-dd-yyyy") & "'"
    Set oItemsInDateRange = olItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

    dateTomorrow = Format$(DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate), "mmm-dd-yyyy")
    dayAfterTomorrow = Format$(DateAdd("d", 2, StartDate), "mmm-dd-yyyy")

    For Each CurrentAppointment In oItemsInDateRange
        If CurrentAppointment.Start >= DateValue(dateTomorrow) And CurrentAppointment.Start <= DateValue(dayAfterTomorrow) Then
            meetingDetails = meetingDetails & CurrentAppointment.Subject & " " & CurrentAppointment.Start & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox ("*** Tomorrow's Meetings ***" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & meetingDetails)

End Sub
```

I need to run it as a standalone file. I tried to save this file as .vbs and run it, but it shows error `Invalid Character` at `Format$`. I also tried to embed the script in an HTA file but the same error is encountered.

Is there a way to run this code in a standalone file?

Comment: Excel VBA and VBScript are different languages. You'd use FormatDatetime() in VBScript. You need to save the code as a ".vbs" file, run it, encounter errors and fix them line by line as you don't seem to have VBScript experience. It should not be hard as the languages are similar and you already know VBA.

Comment: In fact, I am new to VBA as well :), but anyway as you said, one way is to debug the code line by line.

Comment: Curious why you don't just run it in Excel. Do you need to run it on a machine that has Outlook installed but doesn't have Excel installed?

Comment: I want this file to be portable and when I share it with other people, they should be able to run it without much hassle.

Comment: @MikeC: I debugged it and it's now working. The issue was solved with `FormatDateTime`. You can post it as an answer. I will accept.

Comment: Create it as a Module in Excel VBA that way you can save it as a separate BAS file and import it into other Excel instances.

Comment: Here is the VBS help file https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Comment: For guidelines on translating VBA to VBScript see [here](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' StartDate, EndDate, myStart, myEnd variables not needed; so, I removed them
' dateTomorrowWihoutTime variable is not being used; removed it
' dateTomorrow, dayAfterTomorrow are being used as Date Values; so, removed conversion to (and back from) string
' restrictionString is not being used; renamed to strRestriction which is being used.
' "Option Explicit" is needed at the top of the module (both VBA and VBScript) to enforce variable declaration; added it.
' Added some declarations needed
' Initiallized meetingDetails variable outside the For loop; just a matter of practice, not really needed in this case
' Added strMeetings to show additional meeting information in a slightly different format
' Works in Excel VBA and as VBScript without any changes
' Scope for improvement: Optionally send the message text to the default printer

Option Explicit

Sub getMyAppointmentsForTomorrow()
    Dim olItems
    Dim CurrentAppointment

    Dim dateTomorrow
    Dim dayAfterTomorrow

    Dim meetingDetails
    Dim strRestriction
    Dim strMeetings

    Const olFolderCalender = 9




    dateTomorrow = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    dayAfterTomorrow = DateAdd("d", 2, Date)

    Set olItems = CreateObject("Outlook.application").GetNameSpace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalender).items
    olItems.Sort "[Start]"
    olItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

    strRestriction = "([Start] >= '" & dateTomorrow & "') AND ([End] < '" & dayAfterTomorrow & "')"

    meetingDetails = ""
    strMeetings = ""
    For Each CurrentAppointment In olItems.Restrict(strRestriction)
        If (CurrentAppointment.Start >= dateTomorrow) And (CurrentAppointment.Start <= dayAfterTomorrow) Then
            meetingDetails = meetingDetails & CurrentAppointment.Subject & " " & CurrentAppointment.Start & vbNewLine
            strMeetings = strMeetings & CurrentAppointment.Start & " - " & CurrentAppointment.Location & vbNewLine & CurrentAppointment.Subject & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next
    If (Len(strMeetings) > 4) Then ' Eliminate trailing newlines
        strMeetings = Left(strMeetings, Len(strMeetings) - 4)
    End If

    MsgBox ("*** Tomorrow's Meetings ***" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & meetingDetails)
    MsgBox strMeetings, vbInformation, "Tomorrow's Meetings"
End Sub

getMyAppointmentsForTomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after I changed `Format$` to `FormatDateTime` (As pointed out in comments by MikeC). No other changes were needed.

Comment: I saw your comment just now. I'll make the change and test it for myself before posting it as the answer later today. I don't want to post without running the code myself.